# Add a time/delay into a foreach for reading a string / Visual Studio 2019 C# Win Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, foreach, delay

I want to **easily** read a string letter by letter, but **slowly**, and drop it into a textbox.

```
private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string str = "hello world", bar = string.Empty;

    foreach (char c in str)
    {
        bar += c;
        richTextBox1.Text = bar;

        /// delay??
    }
}
```

Comment: `Thread.Sleep(1000)` will sleep for a second

Comment: doesn't work, i got the full string after a time

Comment: That's right, I want to visualize how the letters appear one by one in a textbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn the method async and add an `await` with the desired delay.

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    richTextBox1.Text = string.Empty;

    foreach (char c in "hello world")
    {
        richTextBox1.Text += c;
        await Task.Delay(100);
    }
}
```